# MySQL broken on localhost since update

Tags: apache2, mysql

all.

After a recent 12.04 update (MySQL was updated), when trying to access my localhost site I get the following error:

Database Error: Unable to connect to the Database: The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not available.

However, from a terminal window I can see MySQL running as a service and I can access and use MySQL from there.

Any ideas on what happened ??  Is this a config change I need to do in Apache ??

Thanks in advance !
grpace

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, what happens when you try to log in with the commandline client? `mysql -u <username> -P`

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP5, I think you have to install "php5-mysql" :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: Thank you, madmaze for your reply.  Logging in at the command line was working last week, but now gives me the error:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

using the locate command I find mysqld.sock in my home directory.

Comment: To Benabra: php5-mysql is already installed.

When trying to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin I get:
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. 

Everything was working fine until MySQL was updated through Ubuntu's Update Manager.  I find it really irritating that an update will break things that were previously working.

Any other ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You
grpace